# Structure Push back not working

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct Edge
{
    int from;
    int to;
    int weight;

};

int main()
{
    vector<Edge> v;
    v.push_back(Edge (1,2,10));
    v.push_back(Edge (2,3,30));
    v.push_back(Edge (1,3,20));

    return 0;
   }
```

why push_back function is not working in vector and giving errors? how do I directly insert values in vector and not define a variable of type Edge?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  They should give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: Just use `Edge {1,2,10}` aso., you didn't declare/define this construtor signature.

Comment: You never define any variables of type `Edge`. Variables are things with names. The only variable you have is `v`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Huh?? Variables are needed actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, I didn't say that. I was pointing out that the OP's requirement in the final sentence is already met.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But you made me realize that the OP may be thinking this: The code could be made work by introducing a variable, `Edge e  = { 1, 2, 3 };` and the inserting `v.push_back(e);`; presumably the OP is aware of that and is asking for a solution that doesn't involve a variable.

Comment: It should just work with `v.push_back(Edge{1,2,10});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the answers provided in the comments, you could simply add a constructor inside your struct.

```
Edge(int f, int t, int w) {
    from = f;
    to = t;
    weight = w;
}
```